# Error to grant DBMS_SYSTEM on AWS RDS Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, oracle12c

I am currently trying to grant `Execute` to one of the DB Users on `DBMS_SYSTEM` object. I am currently logged in using master dbadmin account created while instance creation.

Query is as follows:

```
begin
rdsadmin.rdsadmin_util.grant_sys_object(
    p_obj_name     => 'DBMS_SYSTEM',
    p_grantee      => 'USERNAME',
    p_privilege    => 'EXECUTE',
    p_grant_option => false);
end;
/
```

However, it returns following when executed:

```
begin
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20199: Error in rdsadmin_util.grant_sys_object. ORA-20900: You do not have permission to grant DBMS_SYSTEM
ORA-06512: at "RDSADMIN.RDSADMIN_UTIL", line 221
ORA-20900: You do not have permission to grant DBMS_SYSTEM
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

What is the problem here? I have read somewhere that AWS doesn't allow this. Is it true? Is there any way to achieve this somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose ,by default master account does't hold privileges.(Which is ODD I know).You have to provide privilege to the master account.Follow this amazon forum this might help you bit.

[Forum Link-CLICK HERE](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=155616)

Cheers
Mohammed

Comment: It would not allow me to use SYS, SYSTEM or anything inside those packages.
Also, Master account has many privileges, as per this [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.MasterAccounts.html)